# SQL Server: add constraint that compares the date from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have 2 tables:

- Song = { isrc, title, year, artistname }
- Artist = { artistname, startdate, members, genre }

Key:

- Song – isrc

  - artistname in Song is a foreign key referencing Artist
- Artist – artistname

I need add a constraint to table Songs so that in inserted record year must be greater than or equal to artist's startdate (year) so I tried this:

```
alter table Song 
add constraint GreaterThanStartDate 
    check (year > (select startdate from Artist, Song 
                   where Artist.artistname = Song.artistname));
```

It does not work, because check only accept scalar value. So I think I should use a user-defined function:

```
create function CompareStartDate()
returns int
as
begin 
    declare @result int

    if (some condition here)
        set @result = 1
    else 
        set @result = 0

    return @result 
end
```

I am stuck to write the condition in the if statement (I can join Artist and Song tables, but how to compare 2 columns and return 1 or 0). I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: A user defined function is definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the function from the Song table like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CompareStartDate(@artistname varchar(255), @year int)
RETURNS bit
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @result bit

    IF (SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(startdate) FROM Artist WHERE artistname = @artistname) <= @year
        SET @result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @result = 0

    RETURN @result 

END
```

Your constraint would then be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Song
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckYear
CHECK (CompareStartDate(artistname, year) = 1)
```